# Как отвязать базу MSG_.ADT от словаря DICT.ADD с помощью freeadt.exe без админских прав на сервере Windows Server 2019 Standard?

Tags: windows, delphi, ads

Мы написали приложение в 2000 году, которое до сих пор используют наши клиенты. Приложение использует сервер баз данных Advantage Database Server или ADS.

`ADS` использует пароль, если таблица "привязана" к словарю `DICT.ADD` и работает без прав доступа, если таблица не привязана. Для того, чтобы "отвязать" таблицу, например, `MSG_.ADT` от словаря `DICT.ADD` используется их бесплатная утилита `freeadt.exe`

Проблем не было 20 лет, но теперь на сервере Windows Server 2019 Standard эта утилита не может получить доступ к файлу `MSG_.ADT`. Сам сервер баз данных `ADS` снят с поддержки, и мы смогли решить проблему только запустив наше приложение на сервере с правами администратора

Но это же не выход, запускать постоянно приложение с правами администратора, может быть кто-то знает, как можно поступить, чтобы запускать приложение как обычно, но чтобы `freeadt.exe` работала без проблем? Как она и работала последние 20 лет

Прошу совета

Comment: Пока нашли вот такое решение на stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991412/code-sample-for-freeing-advantage-database-server-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решили вопрос

Оказалось, что надо было настроить права в Windows

Мы дали все права на вкладке "Разрешения" и на вкладке "Безопасность" мы добавили группы для пользователей, которые работают с данным сервером ( я говорю про папку, в которой лежит `MSG_.ADT` )

После этого `freeadt.exe` заработала корректно. Видимо была проблема в том, что файл `MSG_.ADT` создавался с такими правами, которых не было у `freeadt.exe` и поэтому при попытке модификации `MSG_.ADT` мы получали ошибку доступа

Просто сначала даже не было понятно в каком направлении надо копать